# document.forms.gallery_form.submit is not a function

Tags: javascript

I swear, I have this exact thing working on another page. I'm such a javascript noob it's embarrassing...

```
function delete_gallery() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery_id').value;
    var form = document.getElementById('gallery_form');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'index.php?action=delete&section=galleries&id='+gallery);
    document.forms['gallery_form'].submit();
}
```

Inspecting the element shows that it's updating the action correctly :

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=delete&amp;section=galleries&amp;id=12" name="gallery_form" id="gallery_form"><input type="hidden" value="12" id="gallery_id" name="gallery_id"><p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Woo"></p><p>Description:<br><textarea name="description">Dee</textarea><input type="hidden" value="2" name="artist"></p><p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </p></form>
```

Here's the button I use to call the function, it's in a table below the form:

```
<button onclick="delete_gallery()" type="button">Delete Gallery</button>
```

EDIT:

I should have mentioned I tried using the getElementById method first, ala forms.submit(); - I had the same error, which is why I switched to using document.forms[] instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably because of this inside the form-

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

`form.submit` is being redefined with this input. Just change the name from `submit` to something else, like `submit1` and see if that works.

Comment: Safari's web inspector agrees with you. I'm not going to steal your great find, so here's how to call form.submit if changing the name of the submit button is too much trouble (though it shouldn't be): `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.getElementById('gallery_form'));`

Comment: Wow. I never would have guessed it. I'll definitely start naming my buttons more creatively from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('gallery_form').submit();
```

and as you already have a reference to the form just submit it:

```
function delete_gallery() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery_id').value;
    var form = document.getElementById('gallery_form');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'index.php?action=delete&section=galleries&id='+gallery);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I tried that as well. When that didn't work, I switched to the way I had it, since all the tutorials do it that way.